# Commutator Identities in Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be elements of a group $G$ and let $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ be the commutator of $x$ and $y$. Then we have the following identities:

- $[x,zy]=[x,y][x,z][[x,z],y]$
- $[xz,y]=[x,y][[x,y],z][z,y]$

My question is, is there any identity for $[x_1x_2\cdots x_m, y_1y_2\cdots y_n]$, generating the identities above? It may not be difficult but I did not find it being discussed.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your question, but you can use these identities and construct identity for $[x_1x_2\cdots x_m, y_1y_2\cdots y_n]$.

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round, you can use the two given identities to deduce more complicated identities, but they will be of course more complicated. There no simple general expression for $[x_1\cdots x_m,y_1\cdots y_n]$. Of course, in a specific situation (such as when $G$ is nilpotent class $2$) when you know that triple commutators are all trivial, the commutator is bilnear,

Comment: An algebraist would observe that the two identities you cite are generators for the recursively definable identity you want.

Comment: @DerekHolt, in the case you mentioned where all triple commutators are trivial, as in general $[x_p,y_q]$ does not commute with $[x_r,y_s]$, when you mention the commutator being "bilnear", the order of $[x_i,y_j]$'s still matters, right?

Comment: Yes, those commutators will indeed commute (if commutators commute with everything, then clearly they commute with each other). For the commutators to commute, you just need derived length $2$, not nilpotence class $2$.

Comment: But derived length two is not enough to give $[[x,z],y]=1$, which is what you need for bilinearity. But this can also apply in specific situations, such as (for the first identity) when $z$ is known to be in $Z_2(G)$.