# A Commutator Identity in Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring (or associative algebra), let the commutator $[A,B]$ be defined as

$[A,B]=AB-BA$.

[I have asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670714/commutator-identities-in-groups) for a general formula for the expression $[x_1\cdots x_m,y_1\cdots y_m]$ in a group $G$ but there does not seem to exist any satisfactory expression. For commutator in rings, there is an identity saying that

$[AB,CD] = A[B,C]D + AC[B,D] +[A,C]DB + C[A,D]B$.

I would like to ask if there is any identity for $[A_1\cdots A_m,B_1\cdots B_n]$ in a ring, generalizing the result above?

Edit: My guess is that it equals to

$(A_1\cdots A_{m-1}[A_m,B_1]B_2\cdots B_n)+(A_1\cdots A_{m-1}B_1[A_m,B_2]B_3\cdots B_n) + \cdots+(A_1\cdots A_{m-1}B_1\cdots B_{n-1}[A_m,B_n])\\+(A_1\cdots A_{m-2}[A_{m-1},B_1]B_2\cdots B_nA_m)+(A_1\cdots A_{m-2}B_1[A_{m-1},B_2]B_3\cdots B_nA_m)+\cdots+(A_1\cdots A_{m-2}B_1\cdots B_{n-1}[A_{m-1},B_n]A_m)\\+\cdots\\+([A_1,B_1]B_2\cdots B_nA_2\cdots A_m)+(B_1[A_1,B_2]B_3\cdots B_nA_2\cdots A_m)+\cdots+B_1\cdots B_{n-1}[A_1,B_n]A_2\cdots A_{m-1})$

Comment: Are you basing your guess on the idea of induction on $n$?

Comment: Yes, @AneeshKarthikC. I suppose that this identity can be found in some textbook on ring theory; I just want to double confirm that my guess is correct.